# Jinja - How to use variable set in one file in another and set default

Tags: jinja2, jinjava

I am new to jinja and need some help with doing the following:

main.tpl has the following content:

```
{%- with PREFIX = "test." %}
{%- set TEST_VARIABLE = "false" %}
{%- include "child1.tpl" %}
{%- endwith %}
```

How can I use TEST_VARIABLE in child1.tpl such that when it is false, I set a property like this to false else true:

```
{%- if {TEST_VARIABLE} == false %}
PROPERTY1=false
{%- else %}
PROPERTY1=true
{%- endif %}
```

I get and error saying unexpected '{' in field name.

Comment: The variable should just be `TEST_VARIABLE` in your `if` statement. Also, `TEST_VARIABLE`  is set to `"false"`, not `false`

Comment: Tried that and get the error :
 expected token ',', got 'false'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your `child1.tpl` file. First, you are using invalid syntax to refer to a variable in your `if` statement. Second, you are comparing a string (`"false"`) with a boolean variable (`false`). This won't do what you want.  Fixing both of these issues gives you:

```
{%- if TEST_VARIABLE == "false" %}
PROPERTY1=false
{%- else %}
PROPERTY1=true
{%- endif %}
```

Using this and your `main.tpl` works without errors. Changing `set TEST_VARIABLE = "false"` to `set TEST_VARIABLE = "something else"` changes the final template output as expected.

---

With your original `main.tpl` and `child1.tpl` as above:

```
$ jinja2 main.tpl

PROPERTY1=false
```

If I modify `main.tpl` to look like:

```
{%- with PREFIX = "test." %}
{%- set TEST_VARIABLE = "something else" %}
{%- include "child1.tpl" %}
{%- endwith %}
```

Then I get:

```
$ jinja2 main.tpl

PROPERTY1=true
```